# swift -- SWRevealViewController prepareForSegue issue

Tags: xcode, swift

I am pretty much good in Objective-c for usage of `SWRevealController`

**In Objective-c** i used code like:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{
    // Set the title of navigation bar by using the menu items
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UINavigationController *destViewController = (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.title = [[menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] capitalizedString];
    // Set the photo if it navigates to the PhotoView
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mainVC"]) {
        MainViewController *mainVC = (MainViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        mainVC.isReveal = YES;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"logOutVC"]) {
        LogOutVC *logOutVC = (LogOutVC*)segue.destinationViewController;

    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"groupsVC"]) {
        GroupsVC *groupsVC = (GroupsVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
        groupsVC.isReveal = YES;
    } else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"setCustomRouteMapVC"]) {
        SetCustomRouteMapVC *setCustomRouteMapVC = (SetCustomRouteMapVC*)segue.destinationViewController;
        setCustomRouteMapVC.isReveal = YES;
    }

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;
        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {
            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };
    }
}
```

How can i use same **code in Swift?**

Can you please help me out regarding this.

Comment: Do you want us to translate your code to Swift?

Comment: Already i used "Swiftfy" also for converting. but it's not helpful to me . I want to know how can we write above code in SWIFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please see the following code I hope it will be helpful to you

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row
    {
    case 0:
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") as? ViewController
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController!)
            navController.setViewControllers([secondViewController!], animated:true)
            self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(navController, animated: true)
            //self.revealViewController.pushFrontViewController:navController animated:YES];
        break;

    case 1:
        let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewController") as? ViewController
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: secondViewController!)
        navController.setViewControllers([secondViewController!], animated:true)
        self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(navController, animated: true)

        break;

    default:

        break;

    }
}
```

Instead of **prepareForSegue** you can write this code in UITableView did select method

**(OR)**

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender { 
// Set the title of navigation bar by using the menu items
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
UINavigationController *destViewController =    (UINavigationController*)segue.destinationViewController
destViewController.title = menuItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).capitalizedString()
// Set the photo if it navigates to the PhotoView
if (segue.identifier.isEqualToString("mainVC")) { MainViewController *mainVC = (MainViewController*)segue.destinationViewController
mainVC.isReveal = YES
 }
 else if (segue.identifier.isEqualToString("logOutVC")) {
 LogOutVC *logOutVC = (LogOutVC*)segue.destinationViewController
 }
 else if (segue.identifier.isEqualToString("groupsVC")) { 
 GroupsVC *groupsVC = (GroupsVC*)segue.destinationViewController
 groupsVC.isReveal = YES
 }
 else if (segue.identifier.isEqualToString("setCustomRouteMapVC")){
   SetCustomRouteMapVC *setCustomRouteMapVC = (SetCustomRouteMapVC*)segue.destinationViewController
 setCustomRouteMapVC.isReveal = YES
}
if ( segue.isKindOfClass(,SWRevealViewControllerSegue.class()) ){
  SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue
  swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue*   rvc_segue,UIViewController* svc,UIViewController* dvc) {
   UINavigationController*    navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController
  navController.setViewControllers(,@[dvc],animated:,false,)
self.revealViewController.setFrontViewPosition(,FrontViewPositionLeft,animated:,true)
 }
 }
}
```

Comment: ThanQ. It's helpful to me